# Link to "learn more" about a tag is unclickable in Google Chrome

Tags: bug, status-declined, tags, stackexchange, user-interface

Link to "learn more" about a tag is unclickable in Google Chrome.

Steps to reproduce bug:

1. Open page to "Ask Question"
2. Start typing in the "Tags" field at the bottom
3. Mouse over any one of the tags
4. Try to click the link that says "learn more".

It's impossible to click this link in Google Chrome (Version 30.0.1599.14 beta-m) but it works just fine in Mozilla Firefox.

I noticed it here on SF first, but this seems to affect all sites on the Stack Exchange network. Is there a more appropriate meta site for this issue?

Comment: It worked fine for me in Chrome 29 on Linux. Be careful with "beta" software :)

Comment: I downloaded and re-installed the current stable version of Chrome (Version 30.0.1599.14 m, apparently) and the problem persists. Running Windows 7 x64.

Comment: The Chrome Release Blog indicates, as of posting, [version 29.0.1547.57 is latest stable](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com/2013/08/stable-channel-update.html). Where did you get 30?

Comment: I wrongly assumed that the Chrome installer would install an old version over the new version. After fully uninstalling Chrome and reinstalling, I can no longer reproduce this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declining as we only support Google v31+ (I know it wasn't the case before, but it's not worth fixing it now).

Comment: Confirmed OK. Cannot reproduce bug in Chrome 32.0.1700.107.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that this only affects Google Chrome beta (Version 30.0), it isn't a problem with Stack Exchange.